# Generate different uuid in every line?

Tags: multiple-cursors, text

I need to replace `guid_here` by different **uuid**.

```
provider [guid_here]
[guid_here] provider
test again [guid_here]
test again2 [guid_here]
test [guid_here] again2
```

I use this approach.

Install package "**uuid**" - [UUID](https://github.com/nicferrier/emacs-uuid)

I need create **uuid** exactly in the cursor place.
To do this I create custom function:

```
  (defun uuid-insert()
      (interactive)
      (require 'uuid)
      (insert (upcase (uuid-string))))
```

and bind to key:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-'") 'uuid-insert)
```

Also I need  package `multiple-cursor` [multiple-cursor](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el)

and here steps.

1. Select **guid_here**

[image]

2. Use `mc/mark-all-like-this`

[image]

3. Press `Del`

[image]

4. Use my custom function `uuid-string` to insert uuid in every line. I must use keybinding for this - `C-c C-'` . If use by function name `uuid-string` it's not work.

[image]

As you can see, now in every line has **different uuid**. Nice.

It's very cool.

Is it best approach to generate uuid in every lines?

Comment: Since you've already found one way to solve your problem, it would be better to stick to describing the problem in the question: how to generate a different UUID on every line. Post the part about using multiple cursors as an answer. [It's perfectly fine and even encouraged to answer your own question if you know the answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 3):

The way I'd do this is with search and replace. You can call Lisp code from a [regexp replacement](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html) with `\,(my-function …)`. So call `M-x replace-regexp` (or `C-M-%` which is bound to `query-replace-regexp` by default). Use `\[guid_here]` as the regexp to search for and `[\,(upcase (uuid-string))]` as the replacement text.

Comment: Emacs is very cool :-)